# Null pointer exception when reading xml file

Tags: java, xml

I have a class named `xmlReader` that have `parse(String path)` and `parseXml(Document doc)` methods.
I define:

```
    xmlReader reader = new xmlReader();
    Document doc =   reader.parse(PATH);
    reader.parseXml(doc);`
```

My `parseXml` method:

```
public void parseXml(Document doc)
{
    Node first = doc.getFirstChild().getFirstChild();
    NamedNodeMap att = first.getAttributes();
    Node id = att.item(0);
    NodeList l = first.getChildNodes();
    System.out.println("id:" + id.getNodeValue());
    for(int i = 0; i < l.getLength(); i++)
    {
        Node temp = l.item(i);
        System.out.println(temp.getNodeName() + ": " +
                temp.getNodeValue());
    }

}
```

The problem: line 3 of `parseXml` method:

When `Node id = att.item(0)` the program get a null ref exception. When debugging I see that the doc is defined `null`. Why is that? 
Its like its not reading the file correctly.

Thanks?

This is my parse(String path) method:

```
public Document parse(String path) 
{
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =
DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = null;

try 
{
    db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Document doc = null;
try 
{
    doc = db.parse(path);
} catch (SAXException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
return doc;
}
```

Comment: "It's like its not reading the file correctly."  Ummm, perhaps it's not reading the file correctly.  How do you know that's not the problem?

Comment: are you sure PATH is correct?

Comment: If `doc` is `null` then indeed the problem is with `doc = reader.parse(PATH);` not with your method.

Comment: There is no way that code will run to att.item(0) if the doc variable is null. Are you sure that is the same "doc" or is it maybe something you found in the objects making up the DOM tree?

Comment: Could you please provide us with the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: Is your method `parse` returning null?

Comment: There is no file not found exception so i dont think there is a problem with the PATH. doc is defined in main class while the parse and parseXml is in another class. maybe there is a problem with the way doc is sent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getAttributes()

Before you do this `Node id = att.item(0);` take a look at the object type of `Node first` by doing `System.out.println(first);` your probably going to see that this is a text element and not an element.

What you've done when you said `Node first = doc.getFirstChild().getFirstChild();` is "give me the first child of the first element, which is probably a text element. What you should be doing is checking for ELEMENT nodes like this, only `Node.ELEMENT_NODE` will have non-null for `getAttributes()`:

```
        NodeList nl = doc.getFirstChild().getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++){
            Node first = nl.item(i);
            if (first.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                System.out.println("first:" + first);
                NamedNodeMap att = first.getAttributes();
                System.out.println("att:" + att);
            }

        }
```